# Using Batarang to debug my Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I know Batarang is a Chrome Extension that allows you to debug pages written with AngularJS.

But can Batarang be used to debug another Chrome Extension that is written with AngularJS?

Searching Google for this has been frustratingly fruitless (whenever you use "Batarang" with "chrome extension" it simply describes Batarang).

I have Batarang installed and I can see it working if I go to a site such as [Fluid](http://fluid.ie/). The Models show up and I can see all the scopes.

But if I have it running against a Chrome Extension page like `chrome-extension://[random_string]/[path_to_html]`, none of the Models data shows up. Is this a limitation of Batarang, or is my Extension page misconfigured somehow?

**UPDATE TO ANSWER QUESTIONS**

The angular application works as expected.

2 javascript errors occur on the page, but I don't believe they're related:

- *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined* - jquery.ba-bbq.min.js:18
- *Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED* - chrome-extension://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic

Comment: Does any angular stuff work on your extension page currently?

Comment: If you open the dev tools on the extension page are there any errors?

Comment: Question updated to answer comments

Answer (score 0):

This extension is broken after the version 0.6.0 You just need to disable it and continue working.